VBA Excel. For each
Please tell me how to make the cycle below work?
arr = Array("H", "J", "L", "N", "P", "R", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Z", "AB", "AD", "AF", "AH")
For Each q In arr
    Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(yyy).Range("q50:q57").Merge
Next q


Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(yyy).Cells(50, q).Resize(8).Merge or Range(q & "50:" & q & "57")

We can use Columns(q).Range("A50:A57") because the Range is always relative to its parent.  For example, A1 will always be the first cell in any Range.
arr = Array("H", "J", "L", "N", "P", "R", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Z", "AB", "AD", "AF", "AH")
For Each q In arr
    Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(yyy).Columns(q).Range("A50:A57").Merge
Next q


Merge in Columns

Sub MergeInColumns()

    ' Define constants.
    Const WORKBOOK_NAME As String = "Test.xlsx"
    Const WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const MERGE_ROWS_ADDRESS As String = "50:57"
    Dim COLUMN_STRINGS() As Variant: COLUMN_STRINGS = VBA.Array( _
        "H", "J", "L", "N", "P", "R", "T", "U", "V", "X", _
        "Z", "AB", "AD", "AF", "AH")
    
    ' Reference the objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks(WORKBOOK_NAME)
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WORKSHEET_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Rows(MERGE_ROWS_ADDRESS)

    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Merge rows in columns.
    For i = 0 To UBound(COLUMN_STRINGS)
        rg.Columns(COLUMN_STRINGS(i)).Merge
    Next i

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Merged in columns.", vbInformation

End Sub


you could first build the range address and then merge it
arr = Array("H", "J", "L", "N", "P", "R", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Z", "AB", "AD", "AF", "AH")
For Each q In arr
    addr = addr & Range(q & 50).Resize(8).Address & ","
Next
Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(yyy).Range(Left$(addr, Len(addr) - 1)).Merge

a shorter version of which would be:
For Each q In Array("H", "J", "L", "N", "P", "R", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Z", "AB", "AD", "AF", "AH")
    addr = addr & Range(q & 50).Resize(8).Address & ","
Next
    Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(yyy).Range(Left$(addr, Len(addr) - 1)).Merge

while the same code with the warmly suggested Option Explicit clause would be:
Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("H", "J", "L", "N", "P", "R", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Z", "AB", "AD", "AF", "AH")
    
    Dim addr As String
    Dim q As Variant
        For Each q In arr
            addr = addr & Range(q & 50).Resize(8).Address & ","
        Next
        
            Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(yyy).Range(Left$(addr, Len(addr) - 1)).Merge


Keep in mind that the Range.Address property has a limitation of 255 characters. You could use .Address(0, 0) to reduce the number of characters. In this particular case, the limit is not exceeded, i.e., it works. One might also think that the merging will get messed up since there are adjacent columns T, U, and V, but this isn't the case, i.e., each column is merged separately as required.

I guess arr is an array of column name.
Pls try.
    arr = Array("H", "J", "L", "N", "P", "R", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Z", "AB", "AD", "AF", "AH")
    For Each colName In arr
        Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(yyy).Range(colName & "50").Resize(8).Merge
    Next colName  

or
    arr = Array("H", "J", "L", "N", "P", "R", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Z", "AB", "AD", "AF", "AH")
    With Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(yyy)
        For Each colName In arr
            Application.Intersect(.Columns(colName), .Range("50:57")).Merge
        Next colName
    End With

